# Examining a single changeset in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

In Mercurial, how do you examine a single changeset?  hg log -l 5 will give me a summary of the newest 5 changesets, but how do I get a list of the files changed in one changeset?  I don't want to do a diff.

Comment: Changed in comparison to what? I don't quite see how you want to do that without a diff.

Comment: I want a list of the files in the diff, but I don't want to see the diff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mercurial - all files that changed in a changeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789442/mercurial-all-files-that-changed-in-a-changeset)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Pass -v to log and it will print out additional information, including a list of files changed.

Example:

```
hg log -v -r<rev> | grep ^files
```

Answer (score 27):

I was looking for the same thing and found the following command, which is more what I was looking for:

```
hg status --change <rev>
```

Found in this [article](http://ewaldertl.blogspot.com/2012/02/show-changed-files-in-mercurial.html).

Comment: worked best for me. uset '.' of course for current REV, `hg status --change .`

Answer (score 13):

If you want to see how did the contents of the files were changed for a given revision you can use:

```
hg diff --change <rev>
```

If you want to see the diff between the current revision and the one you are interested in, you can use:

```
hg diff -r <rev>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of files changed in one specific changeset use --stat option

Example:

```
hg log --stat -r <rev>
```