# Mercurial - all files that changed in a changeset?

Tags: mercurial, diff, changeset

How can you determine all the files that changed in a given changeset?

I'm not looking for a diff in this case, just a list of add/remove/modifications.

`hg log -vprX` does a list of diffs but I just want the files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Examining a single changeset in Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550721/examining-a-single-changeset-in-mercurial)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

If you want to list only files that have changed then you should be using "status command"
The following will list the changes to files in revision REV

```
hg status --change REV
```

Comment: +1, but the OP probably wants the `-n` / `--no-status` flag too.

Comment: For easy copying: `hg status --no-status --change REV`

Comment: +1 This is so much easier to type than `hg status --rev REV~1:REV` which I used to do.

Comment: use '.' for current REV. meaning - `hg status --change . `

Comment: how would you add the condition of who the author is ? i tried adding --author "myname" or -r"authour('myname')" but none work

Answer (score 20):

## Current Committed Revision

```
hg status --change .
```

`.` is shorthand for the current rev, just like `@HEAD` in Git

## Current Uncommitted Revision

```
hg status
```

## Arbitrary Committed Revision

```
hg status --change REV_ID
```

Comment: most simple & accurate answer !

Answer (score 16):

Just remove `p` from your `hg log -vpr` will show the list of files. `-p` means show patch. You can also use a [template](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html) to format the output to your taste.

Comment: I think you will need the following template: --template 'files: {files}\n'

Comment: I believe the {files} is part of the -v flag default template

Comment: hg log -r . --template '{join(files, "\n")}' to newline separate the files

Comment: @Foxichu comment worked for me, but was kinda hacky. actually the upper answer - `hg status --change .` worked better and gave a file action prefix (A\M\D etc) and better relative path

Answer (score 15):

I know the question is for a single changeset, but if you'd like to get all the files modified for a range of changesets, you can do

```
hg status --rev 1 --rev 10 -m
```

Comment: Terrible bad. Files, modified in range is `hg log -r BEGIN:END --template "{files}\n"` as @geoffrey-zheng and @ton wrote **two years ago!!!**

Comment: Sorry about that.  Assumed their answer was for the single changeset.

Comment: In my opinion this answer is not that terrible. `hg status --rev BEGIN --rev END` is: 1. much easier to remember than `hg log -r BEGIN:END --template "{files}\n"`; 2. it prints the files in separate lines without using `sed` (@Eric Lawler) or `join()` (@Foxichu); 3. without the `-m` flag, it displays not only modified, but also added and removed files (the nice standard coloring applies here too); 4. there are `-a` and `-r` flags which allow different filtering; 5. if one doesn't want the status prefix, there's `-n` option, which suppresses it.

Answer (score 2):

Found this question through Googling for a similar concept. To show all files that changed through a *range* of changesets, it's as easy as:

```
hg log -r [start rev]:[end rev] --template "{file_mods}{file_adds}\n" | sed -e 's/ /\n/g' | sort -d | uniq
```

1. `hg log -r [start rev]:[end rev] --template "{file_mods}{file_adds}\n"` will show you a list of each file changed or added in each changeset, from [start rev] to [end rev], with each changeset's files on a new line. Swap `{file_mods}{file_adds}` with `{files}` to show all files modified, added, or removed.
2. `sed -e 's/ /\n/g'` will split all the files to show on separate lines and
3. `sort` will, er, sort the list for you so we can filter the list with uniq
4. `uniq` will filter the list to remove duplicates—files that changed in more than one revision.

Comment: This solution glues together the last modified with the first added file. Also, it doesn't properly deal with spaces in filenames. A `--template`-based solution without these shortcomings could be constructed using `join()` as suggested by @Foxichu.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is an old question and I'm surprised nobody just offered modified code form OP. I got a list of modified/added/removed files (not labeled which is which though) by just running `hg log -v`. Or what I actually needed `hg log -v -l5` to see files that have been modified/added/removed in the last 5 commits (including the ones that I didn't push yet to the repo).

Comment: "nobody just offered modified code form OP" - @Geoffrey Zheng did exactly that ~1h after the question was posted

Answer (score -2):

If you're like most shops, you use a ticketing system to track changes.  If you know the ticket number and want to find all the commits associated with that ticket (assuming you include the ticket number in the commit message), you can use:

```
hg log -k TICKET_NUMBER
```

This does display the all the revisions associated with the ticket.  However, it does not list the files.  You could do use one of the answers above to then get the list of files associated with the revisions.

To make it simpler though, combining the info from the previous answers, you could do the following to search for commits, including files changed:

```
hg log -vk TICKET_NUMBER
```

Comment: This is related to the question.  The poster asked how to get files in a changeset.  Changesets are often related to tickets. My solution shows how to get files related to the changesets associated to a ticket.