# How to get the file count for each revision of mercurial using python script

Tags: python, mercurial

```
import sys
import hglib
import re 

# figure out what repo path to use

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    repo1 = sys.argv[1]    

# connect to hg
client1 = hglib.open(repo1)

for data1 in client1.log("date('>2015-06-01') and date('<2015-09-16')"):

    m = re.findall("\w+\\-\d+", data1.desc.upper())
    if len(m)> 0:     
        data_row = [data1.rev,data1.author,data1.branch,data1.desc,m[0]]
```

This script gives the revision,author,branch,description . I want to get count of files for each  revision. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`status`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3789516/1084416):

```
>>> changes = client.status(rev=[start, end], modified=True, added=True)
>>> len(changes)
6
```

I've [now found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32354296/1084416) you can also do:

```
>>> changes = client.status(change=[start, end])
>>> len(changes)
6
```

Comment: @JayashreeShetty You're welcome. You can upvote and accept the answer if nothing better comes along (c:

Comment: i have done that.                                                                                     `code`                                                                                                                                                                       for data1 in client1.log("date('>2015-09-01') and date('<2015-09-01')"):     
    print data1.rev,len(client1.status(rev=data1.rev,added=True))                               is this the correct way , i need to pass the revision and get the filecounts for each revision

Comment: Looks correct. Does it give you the results you expect?

Comment: if i straight away use `code`   len(client1.status(rev=data1.rev,added=True) it gives 136 as count. But if i loop it using the client1.log loop like i have mentioned above it prints some 14,000 for each revision. I do not have that many files. for each revision it should have printed no. of files that were added. but its doing something else when i use with for loop.

Comment: also i tried this `code` changes = client1.status(rev=["date('2015-09-01')", "date('2015-09-02')"], modified=True, added=True)
print len(changes). gives some 25 records which is fine i think. but in case we give revision instead of date then we get some unexpected result

Comment: I don't know. I've not used `hglib` before starting to answer your question (c: I think if you only supply one rev it will take the difference between the head and the rev. If you want to take changes between each rev you will need to specify the two revs.

Comment: sorry that was by mistake i didnt realize posting it. i have deleted it though