# Why does hglib not allow status for a revision and changes?

Tags: python, mercurial, hglib

To get a list of changes, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3789516/1084416) gives the command line:

```
hg status --change REV
```

But calling **`status`** using **`hglib`** gives an error:

```
>>> client.status(rev=-1, change=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\asdf\envs\stackoverflow\lib\site-packages\hglib\client.py", line 1384, in status
    raise ValueError('cannot specify both rev and change')
ValueError: cannot specify both rev and change
```

Why can't we specify both `rev` and `change`?

In answer to [another recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345436/how-to-get-the-file-count-for-each-revision-of-mercurial-using-python-script), I posted:

```
client.status(rev=[start, end], modified=True, added=True)
```

This works, but I was wondering why the other doesn't. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hg status --change REV` only specifies the `--change` flag, not the `--rev` flag.

The `--change REV` option displays the changes introduced with changeset `REV`. The `--rev REV` options displays the changes between the changeset `REV` and the working directory.

If you try `hg status --change REVx --rev REVy`, you'll have the same error that you see with `client.status(rev=-1, change=True)` Both the `change` and `rev` options take changesets as parameters

Note that `--modified` is different to `--change REV` - the filters the output to show modified files only.

Comment: Ah! So, I should be passing `client.status(change=[start, end])`. That's great. Thank you. It works!

Comment: @Peter Wood When I do that from the command line, `hg status --change start:end` is the same as `hg status --change end`, that is, the changes in `end` relative to its parent. `hg status --rev start:end` shows the changes between `start` and `end`. Or put differently `hg status --change X` is equivalent to `hg status --rev X-1:X`. Does `client.status( rev=[start,end])` also work?

Comment: I don't have time to check now, but will get back to you.